# How can I trigger polymer-build to do babel transpiling from gulp?

Tags: gulp, polymer, babeljs

I have a polymer 1.x project that's been working well, using gulp and polymer-build.  Now I've started using some new components that contain ES6, and I'm having issues.  I could just use babel from Gulp. But I thought polymer-build would do the transpiling for me, right?  How do I make that happen?  I tried a few things in my polymer.json file, but these didn't work.

```
  "builds": [
    {"js": {"compile": true}}
  ],
```

And...

```
  "builds": [
    {"preset": "es5-bundled"}
  ],
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

well, newer version of polymer CLI transpile es6 code fine. Maybe try to update that first. I am using Polymer 1.9 and Polymer CLI 1.3.1. My project is written in ES6 and I don't have any problems with that

my `polymer.json` looks like:

```
"builds": [{
    "name": "prod",
    "js": {"minify": true, "compile": true},
    "css": {"minify": true},
    "html": {"minify": true}
}],
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using polymer 1.9 and polymer-build 1.6, but not using the polymer CLI.  I think my gulp build is not triggering the transpiler for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

`polymer-build` itself does not look for `polymer.json`, but rather it receives parameters that [`polymer-cli` reads from `polymer.json`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/blob/6c23cd6/src/polymer-cli.ts#L99). To actually use the build flags in the JSON file, your Gulp project would have to explicitly read the `polymer.json` and pass the contents to `polymer-build`, as shown in the following:

```
const polymerBuild = require('polymer-build');
const polymerJson = require('/path/to/polymer.json');
const polymerProject = new polymerBuild.PolymerProject(polymerJson);
...
```

See a working example in the [Polymer `custom-build` generator](https://github.com/PolymerElements/generator-polymer-init-custom-build/blob/9fd5c87/generators/app/gulpfile.js#L29-L30).

Alternatively, you could pass the flags directly to `polymer-build` as a JSON object like this:

```
const polymerBuild = require('polymer-build');
const polymerProject = new polymerBuild.PolymerProject({
  builds: [
    {js: {compile: true}}
  ]
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I was already using that sample gulpfile that you linked to above, from the Polymer custom-build generator.  I am loading my polymer.json file as you said, and the build does some work.  The`polymerProject.bundler()` seems to work.  But the output is not transpiled.  It still contains es6 keywords, like `const`.  Seems like the CLI does some other magic to make transpiling happen...